# Is there a way to add multiple properties into an object?

Tags: javascript

For example given

```
const a = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "hi",
}

const c = "54"
const d = "66"
```

I want a to be

```
a = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": "hi",
  "c": 54,
  "d": 66,
}
```

I want to do it in a single line so

```
 a = {c, d}
```

But the above code will get rid of `a`, `b`. Any quick way to accomplish this?

Comment: `a = {...a, c, d}`

Comment: `a = Object.assign(a, { c, d });` should do the job. @VLAZ wops, didn't notice you did answer there already :)

Comment: as mentioned already, spread operator is the shortest way a = {...a, c, d}

Comment: @briosheje not really an *answer*, is it :P

Comment: @VLAZ sounds like an ans... A comment, indeed.... Of a.. likely.. duplicate question, but that's fine. I see you're a man of culture as well.

Comment: Speaking about spread, I have a better question :) whats wrong about this: `const args = { options, ...defaultArgs }` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax)

```js
const a = {
    a: 1,
    b: 'hi',
};

const c = '54';
const d = '66';

console.log({ ...a, c, d });
```

Answer (score 0):

One way is to use `Object.assign`:

```
a = Object.assign({}, a, { c, d });
```

This effectively creates a new object (`{}`), then it copies all properties from your initial object (`a`) then it copies the new properties (`{c, d }`).